# Why is the matrix with a zero on the right diagonal non-invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question 1:
Why is the matrix with a zero on the right diagonal non-invertible? See pic below. Strang 4th edition
[image]

A second question is: why are the non-diagonal cells NOT required to be non-zeros also?

I'm looking for an answer without determinants. That is $A^{-1}$ undoes what A does.

Comment: A zero on the diagonal says nothing about invertibility unless the matrix is triangular.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to start with "A second question is..." when you don't even link to the first question.

Comment: The title is the first question

Comment: How does this have two upvotes? OP: Please edit your question so it is comprehensible.

Comment: @WizardProgramming You forgot to mention it's a *diagonal* matrix. `why are the non-diagonal cells NOT required to be non-zeros also` Because they *are* all $0$ by the definition of a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @dxiv, what is the answer to question 1 then ?

Comment: @WizardProgramming Suppose WLOG that $d_1=0$ then the top row of $A$ is all $0$s. Now multiply $A$ by any matrix $B$ and show that the top-left element in the product will be $0$. Compare that to the identity matrix, and conclude that $A \cdot B \ne I$ for $\forall B\,$. Done.